# Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_up"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am new to stackoverflow and recently I'm learning Ruby on Rails. I can't solve the problem od localhost: No route matches [GET] "/ users / sign_up" (Devise gem).

Here is my code:

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  root 'posts#index'

  get '/about' => 'pages#about'

end
```

In **config/development.rb** I added:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

**Rake routes** shows:

```
post_comments_path  GET /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)  comments#index
                    POST    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)  comments#create
new_post_comment_path   GET /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)  comments#new
edit_post_comment_path  GET /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
post_comment_path   GET /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)  comments#show
                    PATCH   /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)  comments#update
                    PUT /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)  comments#update
                    DELETE  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)  comments#destroy
posts_path  GET /posts(.:format)    posts#index
                    POST    /posts(.:format)    posts#create
new_post_path   GET /posts/new(.:format)    posts#new
edit_post_path  GET /posts/:id/edit(.:format)   posts#edit
post_path   GET /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#show
                    PATCH   /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#update
                    PUT /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#update
                    DELETE  /posts/:id(.:format)    posts#destroy
root_path   GET /   posts#index
about_path  GET /about(.:format)    pages#about
```

I restarted the server but nothing helps. I haven't found a good hint in similar topics.

Thanks

Comment: you forgot to add devise routes. Add `devise_for :users` in routes

Comment: I tried with this but terminal shows me:

'Exiting
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:457:in `ensure in with_devise_exclusive_scope': undefined method `merge!' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x00000007e0a6f8> (NoMethodError)'

Comment: are you using rails 4.2?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: So, its not going to work without users routes in place. Make getting that a question. Not this

Comment: Rails version is 4.2.1

Comment: @Mirek see and answer and please `sign_up` is a `Post` call not `Get's`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution.
In gemfile should be:

> **gem 'devise': git => 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'**

(v. 4.0.0) instead

> gem 'devise' '~> 3.3.0'

Devise 3.3.0 is not compatible with Rails 4.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using default [Devise Routes](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb) as below

```
`/`             `POST`      `Email registration`
`/`             `DELETE`    `Account deletion`. 
`/`             `PUT`       `Account updates`
`/sign_in`      `POST`      `Email authentication`.
`/sign_out`     `DELETE`
```

And `devise_for` `:users` then you don't need to do `user/auth` , instead just use `/` or `/auth` (base on :at option which is defined in devise) for routes
All the routes are well defined in the documents